# REST - JSONrequest mapping to a java object

Tags: java, json, rest, mapping, jersey

I m trying to Map a little bigger JSON  to a Java Object with nested objects. I m using a RESTful WS with Jersey Java.

**Heres a example of the JSON:**

**JSON is now without the user rootKeyPath:**

```
{
        "memberShip": {
            "validTill": "2014-07-19T18:57:30Z",
            "validSince": "2013-07-19T18:57:30Z"
        },
        "userID": "xxxxx",
        "displayName": "xxxx",
        "phoneNumber": "+xxx",
        "country": {
            "iso2DTO": "xxx",
            "short_nameDTO": "xxx",
            "calling_codeDTO": "+xxx",
            "idNumberDTO": 009
        },
        "contacts": [
            {
                "phoneNumber": "xxxxxx",
                "fullName": "xxxxx"
            },
            {
                "phoneNumber": "xxxxxx",
                "fullName": "xxxxx"
            }
        ],
        "device": {
            "name": "xxxx",
            "devToken": "xxxx",
            "systemVersion": "x.x.x",
            "model": "xxxx",
            "systemName": "xxxx"
        }
    }
```

**This is my POST receive methode:**

```
@Path("/user/integrate")
public class IntegrateUser {

    @POST 
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createUserAccount(User user){
        return Response.status(201).build();
    }
}
```

**My User object:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
public class User {
    private Integer ID;

    @XmlElement(name = "displayName")
    private String displayName;
    @XmlElement(name = "phoneNumber")
    private String phoneNumber;
    @XmlElement(name = "status")
    private String status;
    @XmlElement(name = "userID")
    private String userID;

    @XmlElement(name = "country")
    private Country country;
    @XmlElement(name = "device")
    private Device device;
    @XmlElement(name = "memberShip")
    private MemberShip memberShip;
    @XmlElement(name = "contacts")
    private List<Contact> contactsList;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public User() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @return the iD
     */
    public Integer getID() {
        return ID;
    }
    /**
     * @param iD the iD to set
     */
    public void setID(Integer iD) {
        ID = iD;
    }
    /**
     * @return the displayName
     */
    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }
    /**
     * @param displayName the displayName to set
     */
    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }
    /**
     * @return the phoneNumber
     */
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @param phoneNumber the phoneNumber to set
     */
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
    /**
     * @return the status
     */
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    /**
     * @param status the status to set
     */
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
    /**
     * @return the userID
     */
    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }
    /**
     * @param userID the userID to set
     */
    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }
    /**
     * @return the country
     */
    public Country getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    /**
     * @param country the country to set
     */
    public void setCountry(Country country) {
        this.country = country;
    }
    /**
     * @return the device
     */
    public Device getDevice() {
        return device;
    }
    /**
     * @param device the device to set
     */
    public void setDevice(Device device) {
        this.device = device;
    }
    /**
     * @return the memberShip
     */
    public MemberShip getMemberShip() {
        return memberShip;
    }
    /**
     * @param memberShip the memberShip to set
     */
    public void setMemberShip(MemberShip memberShip) {
        this.memberShip = memberShip;
    }

    /**
     * @return the contactsList
     */
    public List<Contact> getContactsList() {
        return contactsList;
    }

    /**
     * @param contactsList the contactsList to set
     */
    public void setContactsList(List<Contact> contactsList) {
        this.contactsList = contactsList;
    }

}
```

So every time i send this request the following error appears:

```
Jul 19, 2013 9:58:00 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "user" (Class de.wazzuup.server.ws.model.User), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@228190; line: 1, column: 10] (through reference chain: de.wazzuup.server.ws.model.User["user"])
```

So what i m doing wrong? I m not sure about the Contacts array mapping. Also about the Xml annotation. Its JSON, do I need the annotations? Please any advice would be great!!

**Edit 1, exception stacktrace:**

```
Jul 21, 2013 2:02:51 PM com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class de.wazzuup.server.ws.model.MemberShip]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@228190; line: 1, column: 16] (through reference chain: de.wazzuup.server.ws.model.User["memberShip"])
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializer.java:740)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:683)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2695)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1308)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
        at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy.readFrom(JacksonProviderProxy.java:139)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:488)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:46)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:203)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1511)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1442)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1391)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1381)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you put the rest of the error message please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that your user object is one level down.  If you can change your JSON input to be:

```
{
    "memberShip": {
        "validTill": "2014-07-19T18:57:30Z",
        "validSince": "2013-07-19T18:57:30Z"
    },
    ...
}
```

That would solve the issue.  Alternatively you could make a `UserContainer` object which just contained the user and use that in the resource method.

You aren't showing your `Contacts` class so I can't talk about that, however you should use `List` rather than `ArrayList` when referring to it in your `User`.

Comment: I m sorry, I dont understand whatI should chasnge in my JSON :S

Comment: Need to see your MemberShip class.

Comment: Ty i had to use the same field names in my Class as in my JSON. The XMLAnnotations were also unnecessary. Also your idea fixed it.